# MVVM: Where to put the database CRUD?

Tags: mvvm

Should the model save/delete itself from the database or should the logic be in the ViewModel? I'm just starting with MVVM so I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

I use repository pattern for CRUD operations. Create a folder named Repositories and put your repositories in it. Then you can call them in your ViewModel.

Comment: Just like in Josh Smith's example?

Comment: Exactly. It also provides you to use IOC container and mock your database repository easily.